# How do I import this module into C++ in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

I have a module that I'd like to install on my Windows laptop:

https://github.com/open-quantum-safe/liboqs

I am using Visual Studio 2019, coding in C++17.

The instructions for the Windows section are unclear to me. It says:

> The same options as explained above for Linux/macOS can be used and build artifacts are generated in the specified build folders.

But when I check the Linux/macOS instructions, they don't work for Windows (or, at least, that's what I think). So, could anyone simplify this for me, please?

Comment: Have you installed the CMake Tools extension yet?

Comment: Yes, sorry that I forgot to specify that...

Comment: Groovy. That's step one down. Have you worked through the documentation on how to use the extension yet? Making sure I understood how to use the tool with basic examples how to use it would be my step two. It's a rare day when you get lucky enough to dive right into configuring and building a third party library complicated enough to need a build automation tool before you've messed around with the tool for a while.

Comment: I found implementation examples: https://github.com/open-quantum-safe/liboqs/wiki/Minimal-example-of-a-post-quantum-signature.

Comment: What next? Didn't quite understand your sentence.

Comment: Make sure you know how to use the CMake Tools extension with something simple before you try to use it with something complicated.

Comment: I do know how to do simple installations, this one just seems out of my scope, any tips?